# Displaying blackboard bold characters in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, amsmath, blackboard

I'd like to display this font of blackboard bold characters:

[image]

Is this included in the amsmath package? If so, it appears to not respond to `\Bbb` or `\mathbb`. So, do I need another package or am I using the wrong functions? If the former, which package will display the above font? I saw that the package {bbold} uses a different font than the one I want.

Comment: amsfonts package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How is amsfonts different from amssymb? I did what Sebastiano's answer said and it worked, but I assume amsfont has perhaps even more symbols or more fonts?

Comment: amssymb includes amsfonts.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the canonical `amsmath` and `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
The blackboard bold letters
$\mathbb{ABCDEFGQRZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]